# How to initial a NSURLRequest with user agent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Usually the http user-agent is like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341
```

If I

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newUserAgentRequest = (NSMutableURLRequest*)[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
    NSString *userAgent = [newUserAgentRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

the userAgent is nil or empty means

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newUserAgentRequest = (NSMutableURLRequest*)[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
```

no user-agent includes, how to initial a request with user agent?

Comment: Setting "User_Agent" (underscore) works for some, but not all, websites.  The built in NSURL classes love to override User-Agent (dash), which means you'd have to <shudder> method swizzle.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks for reply. What do you mean " <shudder> method swizzle"?

Comment: @CodaFi Your comment could as well be an accepted answer, or a +1 from me atleast.

Comment: Alright, Praveen, I'll put it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `User_Agent` (with an underscore) field works for some, but not all websites, and isn't usually overridden by the NSURL... classes.  The other alternative, besides messing with the dictionary (which I believe is not allowed, but I'll post an example anyhow), is method swizzling.

```
+ (void)initialize {
    // Set user agent (the only problem is that we can't modify the User-Agent later in the program)
    NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341", @"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
    //only under MRC do we release [dictionnary release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CodaFi, in your sample, need to custom User-Agent, I still want to set the user-agent as usually `"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341"` like this, do you know how to get this info? Second, you said "which I believe is not allowed", means your sample is not allowed from Apple?

Comment: I'm racking my brains and the interweb to try and remember... I can remember there being some stink about this a while back.  But the only way to really test it would be to submit an app.  So I guess you're in the clear.  And to do what you want, I'll edit the sample.

Comment: @CodaFi I also need to do same thing, I created the nsmutablerequest category and write method inside that, but it does not work.Please share where to place this code to make it work.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I have only done it like the following. This is for iOS devices:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] 
                                       initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[yourURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
NSString *userAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName,[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion];
[urlRequest setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: work for UIWebView? `[self.webView loadRequest: urlRequest];`

Comment: I don' see why not. Try and let us know.

Comment: cos I try the code in `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` after reset request user agent I don't know how to connect with newRequest with the request, I tried `request = newRequest;` seems not correct...

Comment: I could not exactly understand what you meant here. But have a look at this : [User-Agent](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-ipad-get-user-agent-for-uiwebview/)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
NSString *userAgent = @"My user agent";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:9000"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

The User-Agent is set later if you do not provide one yourself, so it is `nil` when you try to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not subclass NSMutableURLRequest, and in the constructor of your subclass, simply set the "User-Agent" HTTPHeaderField. This will have a less pain point of you always remembering to set the header whenever creating an instance.

Comment: Created a class-> MyURLRequest : NSMutableURLRequest
    - (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    if ((self = [super initWithURL:URL])) {
 UIWebView *webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        [self setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"user-agent"];
    }
    return self;
}